# Magento 2 install with baseUrl "http://localhost": Can't add product to the cart in Chrome

Tags: magento2, base-url, localhost

Today I've created a vanilla installation of Magento 2:

- Magento CE 2.0.3
- Vagrant
- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 7.0.3
- MySQL 5.6.28
- URL: http://localhost/

Out of the box, when I try to add a product to the cart in Chrome it doesn't work:

- The cart changes to a spinner icon
- The text on my button changes to 'Adding...'
- That's it ...

The same goes for reviews. When I try to add a review, it doesn't work.

However... when I try it in Firefox it works!

Can anyone tell me why it isn't working in Chrome?

Answer (score 6):

Just figured it out! Apparently Chrome doesn't play nice with cookies when they are single-level domain (like `localhost`). Changing my environment to `localhost.dev` and mapping it in my hosts-file and changing the configuration of Magento 2 solved this problem!

I'll leave this answer here to save other people hours of debugging and mashing their head on their keyboard.

Comment: THIS! Please read detailed explaination here: http://alankent.me/2015/04/25/use-of-localhost-when-installing-magento-2-quick-note/

Comment: good comment  @Maddy. I also heard of problems with local dev domains

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem which is mention above,
I change localhost to 127.0.0.1 and problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

1. Please change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`,
2. To change directly from database Goto -> `core_config_data` table
3. Then change secure and unsecure base url

**http://localhost/ to http://127.0.0.1**

Answer (score 0):

Those who don't wish to change the localhost url and doesn't want to add vhost for this problem. Here's the [quick fix](http://magehelper.blogspot.in/2017/03/magento-2-cannot-add-products-to-cart.html).

The problem is due to form_key mismatch. The form key which gets posted during add to cart action is getting mismatched with store session form key.

Go to

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php execute()

method.
and comment out the first If condition.

**NOTE:**This is not a recommended solution for Production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Infact, this is not a Magento issue, it’s that web browsers behave differently when used with a domain name like "localhost" with less than 2 dots in it. In this case the cookies are not saved and hence creates problem.

For this I suggest you to use one of two given solutions  :

> 1. Either use 127.0.0.1  OR your ip address as domain during installation or replace localhost to 127.0.0.1 OR your ip address from base url from database

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://127.0.0.1/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'https://127.0.0.1/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/secure/base_url';
```

> 2. Or use virtual hosts from /etc/hosts in linux and C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts in windows.
>
> For eg : Add below code at the last line of your host file where "project.dev" is your new domain name.

```
127.0.0.1  project.dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the apache2.conf file.

1. Open and edit the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
2. Navigate to the place in the apache2.conf file `<Directory /var/www/>`
3. Change  `"AllowOverride None"` to `"AllowOverride All"`
4. Save the file
5. Restart **apache2** by `sudo service apache2 restart`