# Magento 2: After upgrading Checkout page Shows Blank & Minicart to 0

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, cache, mini-cart

After upgrading from Magento 2.1.2 to 2.1.3.

I already Added Product, but once i click on Checkout is shows Mini Cart to 0

On Checkout Page It shows Cart Product Count 0 in Mini Cart & Apart from Header & Footer is shows blank area.

Not able to find anything in Log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues solution is below

1] [Magento 2 install with baseUrl "http://localhost": Can't add product to the cart in Chrome](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101257/magento-2-install-with-baseurl-http-localhost-cant-add-product-to-the-cart)

2] **Amasty_Promo** Modules JS is Conflicting on Checkout Page. Right now Disabled module & working fine.